# Can't capture google search URL using jnetpcap

Tags: java, network-programming

I am developing an application to capture all HTTP urls. I used pcap.LOOP_INFINATE for persistent capturing, but when i search on google, it does not capture any packets. Kindly give me a solution for this.

This is my sample code:

```
int snaplen = 64 * 1024;          
int flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS; 
int timeout = 10*1000;
Pcap pcap =   Pcap.openLive(device.getName(), snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);  

PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  
    final Tcp tcp = new Tcp();  

    final Ip4 ip = new Ip4(); Arp arp=new Arp();Payload payload = new Payload();
    Ethernet eth=new Ethernet();Http http = new Http();Udp udp=new Udp(); 

    public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) { 

        if (packet.hasHeader(tcp) && packet.hasHeader(http)) {  

            if(tcp.destination() == 80) {

                if(http.hasField(Http.Request.Accept) && http.fieldValue(Http.Request.Accept).contains("text/html")) 
                {

                    String host = http.fieldValue(Http.Request.Host);
                    String url = host + http.fieldValue(Http.Request.RequestUrl);
                    String referer =  http.fieldValue(Http.Request.Referer);
                    System.out.println("Request: " +" - " + url);
                }
            }
        } 
        } 
};  
pcap.loop(pcap.LOOP_INFINATE,jpacketHandler, null);
```

Comment: google search uses https, e.g. port 443 and not port 80. And it is encrypted, so you will not get usable data by simple packet capture.

Answer (score 0):

> google search uses https, e.g. port 443 and not port 80. And it is encrypted, so you will not get usable data by simple packet capture
>
> -- Steffen Ullrich

Comment: Dont just copy someones comment and put it as an answer

Comment: Probably a question for meta, but, @Chausser ... why not? Steffan has enough history here to know that comments are ephemeral, and that if he wants rep, he should answer. Hell, you don't need rep to answer, but you do, to comment. What would be wrong is to copy an answer, and post it as a comment. The right place for this information is as an answer.

Comment: Because copying someone else comment and posting it as an answer is doing so only to possibly gain reputation. SO is meant to be a quality question and answer service. By simply "moving" information in a comment to an answer you are not providing any additional substance. It is also a possibility that he posted it as a comment and not as an answer for other reasons. There is a post in meta that i cant seem to find right now that basically says rep only actions are frowned upon and to only do things that add quality and substance to the site.

Comment: @Chausser - and all meaningful information in any comments should be edited back in to answers, or the question, and not left in comments.... the attribution is appropriate, I agree.

Comment: And i agree, the problem i have with it is that it is a straight rip. With nothing else added. If someone feels that a comment answers the question then suggest the that the person who posted the comment move it. Or if you are going to use it yourself to answer the question add your own substance to go along with someone else work

Comment: @Chausser If someone posts a comment instead of an answer, then it is perfectly fine for someone to copy that content and post it as an answer as long as attribution is provided - which was done via an edit.